# $f$ attains its minimum, delta definition

Tags: functions, definition

I just want to check if the following "definition" makes sense and is correct:

A function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ attains its minimum if $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $f(x) \geq \delta$, for all $x \in X$.

Comment: What if $\delta < 0$? Also this is global minimum.

Comment: @HenryW. Yes, I'm not too sure why there's a restriction to $\delta > 0$ here. If it helps with making sense of where this came from, this is one of the claims made during a proof of the Lebesgue number. Perhaps this is a case of the XY problem? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: In the proof of Lebesgue number lemma, the function $f$ is defined to be some finite sum of metrics, which is never negative, and $f$ cannot be $0$.

Comment: @HenryW. So this is why we've restricted $\delta$ to a positive number? Furthermore, why is it important to make the distinction that this is a global minimum?

Comment: Yes, because it is safe to do so. The distinction becomes important if $X$ is endowed with some topology.

Comment: @HenryW. Thank you very much! I'll keep this in mind when we extend this to topology. Would you perhaps like to formulate an answer so I can accept one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: This is a formulation of the comments.

For any general mapping $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$, the restriction $\delta > 0$ must be removed. However, in your case of [Lebesgue number lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma), the function $f$ is a finite-sum of metrics, which is never negative. The proof also shows that $f \neq 0$, so it is safe to assume that $\delta > 0$.

Furthermore, the definition you are using is the **global minimum**, which is different from local minimum when $X$ is endowed with some topology.